# Python 2.3 on Leopard

Tags: python, macos, osx-leopard

Is anybody using Python 2.3 for Leopard?  If so, could you please tell me what you did to get it to work.

Thanks.

Edit: I'm trying to run this (http://sourceforge.net/projects/decompyle/) and it appears that it needs Python 2.3 (doesn't install on 2.4, 2.5, or 2.6).  If somebody can advise on how to do that without Python 2.3, even better!

Comment: What did you do, and what isn't working? Specific details will be helpful in diagnosing whatever problem you are having.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is "hopefully not."

Comment: Based on the comments, I have edited above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: **DONT**.

If you absolutely have to do so [here](http://blogs.nuxeo.com/fguillaume/2005/05/compiling-python-2-3-5.html) is how to compile it on Tiger, it'll work on Leopard too. But beware that some stdlib features might not work, so you are on your own here.